# Can't display new site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, web-application, sharepoint-server, setup

I'm going through the steps to create a site collection but after I created it, I can't access it via "intranet.contoso.com". I keep getting the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Things I've tried:

- Disabled loop back checking
- Added to the host file
- Restarted IIS
- Flushed DNS

I'm not really sure what else to do. When I tried to ping the host (intranet.contoso.com) it times out. This is what I have in the [display all site collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Ajg.png).

For some reason the option to create a new web application is greyed out so I can't even start from the beginning unless I role back the VM's which I don't really want to do.

Comment: Have you checked for the Application Pool.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ltFElOe.png
I went into it before and noticed "SharePoint Web Services Root" was off so I turned it on but it didn't help.

Comment: I won't ideally recommend..but let's restart VM if possible.
I am unable to figure out the issue. Also try accessing the site and central admin with Application pool A/C. Also check the managed path.

Comment: I've restarted the SP Server VM a few times but not the SQL server. The SQL is on it's own VM. I'm not sure what you mean by Application pool A/C. I went to managed paths and this is what I got http://i.imgur.com/gZPi3Gg.png

Comment: Pls share the webapplication list of your server.
As I can see the Managed path is correct.
Application pool A/C is the the account with which your application pool is running.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2005/06/14/428862.aspx

Comment: My webapplication list: http://i.imgur.com/5bk0foX.png

Answer (score 1):

I guess I got the problem at your end.
You have set the url for your web app as http://interanet.contoso.com. Now this DNS mapping is not correct as it does not exist on your server.

```
You must not have changed it. When you would have created Sharepoint would have set the default value http://sp2010-wfe:80 initailly.
Since the Central admin url for you is http://sp2010-wfe:1433
```

So two approches are there either update the web app url through powershell or create a new one with the default url.

[MSDN update wep app url](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/02/27/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: So the problem is that my central admin is at port 1433 instead of 80?

Comment: no...I got me wrong no problem with Central Admin. You assigned http://interanet.contoso.com this url for ur web app is mistake. I guess you got it from MSDN. This must be http://sp2010-wfe:80

Comment: so intranet.contoso.com should be changed to sp2010-wfe:80? Why would that be the case?

Comment: It seems that you should know more about DNS maapping. Tell me how the IIS will know contoso.com is hosted on your machine...?
Okay so just do one thing modify your hosts file.
It is loacted at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
Open the host file with notepad and add the following line at the end 
your VM IP http://interanet.contoso.com
Save the file and check

Comment: When I created the site, I set the ip to 10.0.0.21. I've taken that and intranet.contoso.com to the host file but that didn't help.

Comment: so has the option to create new web app started working

Comment: Yes, I can create a new web application now.

Comment: so try for a fresh one and don't set the url as contoso...let it be like sp2010-wfe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9803/discussion-between-batman-and-pushpendra)

Comment: I don't understand why I have to use sp2010-wfe. I tried doing it with a new site called intranet.beta.com but that didn't work either.

Comment: come to discussion ..i am there

Answer (score 0):

In IIS have you checked to see if the Default web site is stopped?

Comment: It says "restart" so I assume it's on. But it has a question mark on the Globe Icon. I'm not sure if thats a bad thing or not http://i.imgur.com/Yk4DY3W.png

Comment: Your graphic indicates your Default site is running.  Click stop on the right under Manage Website.  It is handling the web traffic.  That's why it is not getting to contoso.com

Comment: I turned it off but it didn't help. Like another user asked me to try to do it using only default values and it worked fine but when I try to give it a name or change the host header, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check your managed paths? Is that still showing the path to the site collection that you wanted to place there?

Comment: I haven't checked that, i'm not really sure what that means.

Comment: I looked into it and see this http://i.imgur.com/gZPi3Gg.png
I clicked "Check URL" but nothing resolves.

Comment: can you try to add a new path, (explicit) and then go to App management and create a new site collection on that managed path and then see if you can navigate to the site.

Comment: yea I'll give that a shot, the new managed path, do I give it a random name?

Comment: well if you're just testing stuff for now then it doesn't matter, but that will be the URL to your site (//server/managedpathname/)

Comment: right now i'm just using it for training and want it to work